# Making my own furry windscreen

Tags: wind-protection, diy

So I've seen things about making your windscreens and such. Usually they pertain to constructing a zeppelin or something. I have a shotgun mic with a foam windscreen on it, but it just isn't cutting it. They have cheap furry covers for foam screens on ebay and such, but international shipping to Japan plus the fact I spent so damn much on mics, pre-amps, etc. I just am looking for the cheapest possible fix.

So question is, obviously I need to find some furry fabric, but what do I need to look for in terms of the material the furry part is attached to so it doesn't color my sound?

And then I need to learn how to sew.... >_<

Answer (score 2):

Hi. Firstly, there are methods shown on YouTube of how to make your own windshields so you might be able to follow one of those videos. But to be honest, if you've spent a lot of money on mics you should buy the proper wind protection! What is the point in having an expensive microphone with a windshield that may not be up to the job. I will always go for the items that are designed for the job, my personal preference is Rycote!

Comment: I agree with @Si Charles. If you spent a lot of money on a nice signal chain you don't want to cheap out on something simple. You wouldn't plug a Neumann into M-audio pre and expect great results, for example.